# Extending die roll simulations for complex data science tasks

Tags: python, beginner, pandas, matplotlib

I've developed a Python script that simulates die rolls and analyses the results. I'm now looking to extend and modify this code for more complex data science tasks and simulations.

- Is this code simple and readable?
- Are there more insightful statistics or visualisations that can be generated from the die roll data?
- How could this code be extended or modified for more complex data science tasks or simulations?

```py
import unittest
from random import randint

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def roll_die() -> int:
    """Simulate rolling a fair six-sided die and return the result"""
    return randint(1, 6)


num_rolls = 1000
die_rolls = [roll_die() for _ in range(num_rolls)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Rolls": die_rolls})
roll_counts = df["Rolls"].value_counts().sort_index()

print(df)
print(roll_counts)

plt.bar(roll_counts.index, roll_counts.values)
plt.xlabel("Die Face")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title("Die Roll Distribution")
plt.show()


class TestRollDie(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_roll_die(self):
        result = roll_die()
        self.assertTrue(1 <= result <= 6)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas should not be used for this purpose. Just use bare Numpy.

Do not generate random numbers one at a time. Use the vectorised Numpy random number generator.

Rather than `value_counts` on a dataframe, use `bincount` on an `ndarray`.

Prefer the Matplotlib OOP interface over the non-reentrant interface.

It's good that you've started writing unit tests, but... the unit test you've written isn't very useful - it's just testing `randint` itself (something that should already be working, and is tested in this case by the Python test suite).

For reproducible results, set a seed before calling random routines within a simulation.

### Suggested

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_rolls = 10_000
n_sides = 6
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
die_rolls = rand.integers(low=1, high=1 + n_sides, size=n_rolls)
roll_counts = np.bincount(die_rolls)[1:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(np.arange(1, 1 + n_sides), roll_counts)
ax.set_xlabel('Die Face')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_title('Die Roll Distribution')
plt.show()
```

[image: distro]

### Questions

> Is this code simple and readable?

Basically, yes

> Are there more insightful statistics or visualisations that can be generated from the die roll data?

That's impossible to answer, because it's a trivially simple simulation and (as the kids say) "there isn't a lot of there there". You could plot a kernel density estimate, or an empirical cumulative PDF; but these would not be interesting since the distribution is so simple.

> How could this code be extended or modified for more complex data science tasks or simulations?

Impossible to answer. Different things are different.